# How to write an NFC with payload to open the app?

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

What I want to achieve is that when you press a `Button`, an application-type payload is written to an NFC to open a specific app specifying the app's package. I have looked at some examples of NFC writing but I only find plaintext writings and not of this type. How could it be achieved?

Comment: Depends on exactly you want to do, just launch a specific application or launch a specific application and send it some data from the NFC card and it can depend on what application.

Comment: Perhaps I have not explained myself clearly. What I want to do is that when an empty NFC approaches the mobile, when pressing a button, write in the empty NFC, an application type payload so that every time the NFC approaches, open that application (without parameters, only open the app). This can be easily achieved with the NFC Tools app by writing the app package and setting the application type but I want to be able to do it in my own application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing a Text Record in the examples you have seen write an AAR record https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#aar

so instead of `ndefRecord.createTextRecord` method to a text record to add to your `MdefMessage` use `ndefRecord.createApplicationRecord`

[Link to reference docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord#createApplicationRecord(java.lang.String))

You just need to work out the package name of the App you want to start (note that if that is not installed the AAR record will launch the play store to install it)